# Django admin dropdowns based on a boolean

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-admin

I am wondering how to filter a drop down based on a boolean. Say one of the objects is `True`, then it would be displayed but if it is `False` then it would not be displayed.

Any help would be great. Here is a copy of my models and admin file

**models.py**

```
class Airports(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField("ID", primary_key=True, editable=False,)
    airporticao = models.CharField("Airport ICAO", max_length=6, help_text="Example: CYYZ or KLGA")
    airportname = models.CharField("Airport name", max_length=50, help_text="Example:")
    country = models.CharField("Country", max_length=50, help_text="Example: Canada")
    hub = models.BooleanField("Hub?", default=False)
```

**admin.py** for profiles module:

```
class UserProfileadmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['user', 'country', 'vatsimid', 'totalflights', 'totalhours', 'hub']
    search_fields = ['user']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh. Try this:

```
class UserProfileadmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'hub':
            kwargs['queryset'] = Airports.objects.filter(hub=True)
        return super(UserProfileadmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Documentation on [formfield_for_foreignkey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey).

Comment: Hi Pavel, Well it is sort of like that but a bit different. Here is a picture to better explain 'http://i.imgur.com/g1eOE.png'. I would want to filter out the airport in the red box but keep the airport in the green box.